# Passing args in kotlin using safe args plugin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, parameter-passing, android-safe-args

I want to pass args by safe args in kotlin (android studio). No matter what I try I am always getting this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJF8F.png) in  [onCreateView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJZJ5.png). Require arguments are in red. On alt+enter it wants to create new function but that is not what I need. Does anyone know what could be problem and how to fix it.

Edit: [Imprts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPzvF.png)

[Imports 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIxwf.png)

[dependencies in gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCxzq.png)

Comment: can you share your imports?

Comment: @DinkarKumar I have edited post and added more imports

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import androidx.navigation.fragment.navArgs
```

Try with declaring an instance variable like
   `private val args: KrajFragmentArgs by navArgs()`
And then get data from `args` variable.

Answer (score 0):

May help you using new fragment version:

You need to add the Google Maven repository to your project's build.gradle file in order to include this dependency.

```
buildscript {
    ...

    repositories {
        google()
        ...
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        ...
    }
}
```

To include the AndroidX Fragment library to your project, add the following dependencies in your app's build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    def fragment_version = "1.3.4"

    // Java language implementation
    implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment:$fragment_version"
    // Kotlin
    implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:$fragment_version" }
```